# How to search in single field solr

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

I am using SolrJ api for searching. I have already indexed tables from my database but I have problem when trying query fields.

> ```
> query.setQuery("Jack");
> query.setFields("Name", "City", "Spouse_name");
> query.setStart(0);    
> query.setRows(100);   
> QueryResponse response = solr.query(query);
> ```

Like in example code when I query "Jack" I want to search only in field "Name" and only print resoults from rest fields but when I query searching "Jack" in "Name" and "Spouse_name". Can someone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: which version of solr are you using?

Comment: Did you index the rest of the fields other than name? means indexed= true?

Comment: Yeah so i have to change only indexed= false in schema.xml? :)

Comment: try this way SolrQuery query=new SolrQuery("q=name:Jack"); and then setFields and other code... query.setFields("Name", "City", "Spouse_name");
  query.setStart(0); query.setRows(100);                           QueryResponse response=solr.query(query);

Comment: SolrQuery solrQuery=new SolrQuery().setQuery("name:Jack")

Comment: It work i used  SolrQuery query=new SolrQuery("name:Jack"); thanks alot :)

Comment: could you please accept it as an answer... :)

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
SolrQuery query=new SolrQuery("name:Jack"); 
query.setFields("Name", "City", "Spouse_name"); 
query.setStart(0); 
query.setRows(100); 
QueryResponse response=solr.query(query)
```